# finding the indices of max values(more than one) in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the row indices of max values appearing in a column. I got one index using argmax() and idxmax() but there are other indices that have the same value as the max. How could I solve such problems?

Comment: Can you share the sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose your dataframe is called df, and your column is called col.

You want to get the index of every row where the value of a column 'col' is equal to the maximum value of that column.

```
df[df.col == df.col.max()].index
```